# 24 hour Countdown timer using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I need a 24 hour countdown timer like the image in the link. I need to implement the timer to my wordpress site. The timer should reset every night at midnight EST.

This is my current JS Code but it restarts each time i refresh the page. Can I somehow integrate it with EST?

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">

var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs) {
timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000); 
}

function tick( ) {
var secs = timeInSecs;
if (secs > 0) {
timeInSecs--; 
}
else {
clearInterval(ticker);
startTimer(172800);  // start again
}

var hours= Math.floor(secs/3600);
secs %= 3600;
var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
secs %= 60;
var pretty = ( (hours < 10 ) ? "0" : "" ) + hours + ":" + ( (mins < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + mins + ":" + ( (secs < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + secs;
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = pretty;
}

startTimer(86400);  // 24 hours in seconds

</script>

<span id="countdown" style="font-weight: bold;"></span>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions on this site work best if you show what you have tried in terms of research and coding, and explain a particular problem you are having with your code. This question is instead asking either for code to be written for you, for free, or for a list of links to existing code which you could probably find yourself with a search engine.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take another look at this when I am home, your problem however is that every time your page loads you are calling the startTimer() method, what you need to do is get the current system time (in EST format) and convert that to seconds
That way when your page refreshes you will have the current time and not your current defined constant - I hope this is a basis for you to find a solution.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate how I might define that value and insert it for the "time" variable? Can I get the value of EST instead of my local system time from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. as Alex said, I need to get current system time(EST). I came up with index.html and server_time.php files.Here are codes for both files

INDEX.HTML

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Countdown</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
<script>
    var root_path = "http://localhost/countdown/";
    function init(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: root_path + "server_time.php",
            beforeSend: function(aj_msg) {
                //$("#countdown").html('');
            },
            success: function(aj_msg){
                $("#countdown").html('');
                phpMsg = JSON.parse(aj_msg);
                var est = "<span>" + Math.abs(phpMsg['ServerTime'][0].hour) + " :</span> ";
                est += Math.abs(phpMsg['ServerTime'][0].minute) + " : " ;
                est += Math.abs(phpMsg['ServerTime'][0].second);
                $("#countdown").html(est);
            }
        })
    }

    setInterval(init, 1000)
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="countdown"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And server_time.php

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
    $currenttime = date('G:i:s:u');
    list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);
    $output = '{"ServerTime": [';
    $hrs -= 24;
    $mins -= 60;
    $secs -= 60;
    $output .= '{ "hour":"' . $hrs . '" , "minute":"' . $mins . '", "second":"' . $secs . '"}'; 
    $output .=']}';

    echo $output;
?>
```