# I want count down timer of $time value in php

Tags: php, jquery

The timer must stop when 24 hrs completed from the time of $time. It means when i recieve the value of $time. counting down till 24 hrs from then the timer must stop.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos"); 
 $time  =  `enter code here`date('H:i:s', time() - date('Z'));
 echo $time;
?>
```

Comment: Your problem appears to be the part where it says `enter code here`. Did you try putting some code there? Try this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicated with the post
<br>
[24 hour Countdown timer using Javascript and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893244/24-hour-countdown-timer-using-javascript-and-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [24 hour Countdown timer using Javascript and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893244/24-hour-countdown-timer-using-javascript-and-php)

Answer (score 1):

It's really better that you do this in JavaScript or jQuery. PHP isn't really meant to do stuff like that. However, if you want something to happen in 24 hours you could set up a cronjob. However, PHP is a preprocessor for HTML. It's supposed to help create the necessary HTML and have it sent back to the browser. The file will literally be loading for 24 hours before it finally stops loading to say timer complete. Also with modern browsers, it could time out.

Comment: I have done already in javascript but i am unable to hold the value till 24 hrs.

Comment: Why don't you store two cookies on an interval. One that specifies when those cookies were last updated, and another that says how much time was left on the timer at the time it was last updated. If the browser refreshes or the user closes the tab and then goes back to it, you can calculate how much time has past since the cookies were updated, and subtract that amount from the Time Remaining cookie and have the timer start there. With that, the timer will be preserved through page refresh, accidentally closing browser/tabs, etc.

Comment: If you could help with some code, that will be better for me or for someone else trying for the same..